# how to check the table column file in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel-5

> I have a query in my controller

```
$checkAccountCounter = Counterlogin::where('uid', '=', $name)->first();
```

> counterlogin table have a column name activeidle,pwd etc.

```
 if ($result[activeidle]=='y')
    {

   /* conditions*/
    }
```

> but i don't know how can i check the column "activeidle" value in
>   laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following instead of yours if condition.

```
if(count($post) && $post->activeidle=='y') {
    // code here 
}
```

This will check if there is any record and that record object activeidle column value = 'y'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function User(Request $request)
{
    $post = Posts::where('post_id', $request->session()->get('post_id'))->first();

    if(!count($post) == 'active') {
        $post = Posts::firstOrNew(['post_id' => $request->session()->get('shopId')]);
    }
    return view('post.index')->(['post' => $post]); or
    return view('post.index',compact('post'));
}
```